# Cant seem to change the image size without changing the header size

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website using a template, and I am trying to make an image the same height size as the header size.  But whenever I am changing the image size it stretches the header as well. Here is the code.

```css
    body {
     background: url(../newImages/headerBackground.jpg) repeat;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     //font-size: 14px;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
           
    }

    #header {
     background: url(../images/bg-header.png) repeat-x bottom center;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 0 20px;
    }
    
    #header img {
     display: block;      
     height: 190px;
     margin: 0 auto; 
     width: 230px;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-top:2px;
            
            
    }
    
    #header ul {
     background: url(../images/menu-border.gif) no-repeat bottom left;
     margin: 0 auto;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 0 0 0 1px;
     width: 970px;
            position:relative;
            left:5%;
           
            
    }
```

```html
       <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <!-- Website Template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
        <html>
        <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>Academy Website Template</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>
         <div id="header">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/230x190">
          <ul>
           <li class="selected">
            <a href="index.html">home</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="about.html">Opportunities</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="admission.html">Project Management</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="programs.html">About Jay</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="calendar.html">Community</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="blog.html">Contact</a>
           </li>
           
          </ul>
         </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Since the header has a fixed height, did you try `img { max-height: 100%; }`?

Comment: #header img {
 display: block;      
 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 width: 230px;
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-top:2px;
        max-height: 100%;
        height:70%;
        
        
}Something like that? that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNbLLM

I have removed some of your code (the ul list) for testing purposes.

Noticed some errors on your CSS too.

Remove or put padding:0 on

```
#header {
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}
```

Remove:

```
#header img {
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

Comment: So that never ended up working either, i am still getting about 10px extra of the header image underneath the image everyime i choose a different height

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding the following lines to your css file:

```
#header {
     padding: 0px;
}
```